# Html Can you run css code from javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, background-image

I am making a canvas on my website that you can draw on. To achive this effect I draw a fillRect everytime the mouse moves, at the mouseposition. Everithin works fine but when i try to add a background image, it hides everything. I tried using `canvas.drawImage();`

Then I found that you can add Background image from CSS, using: `background:url(pic1.jpg);`

This workes fine, but I dont want to the image to be there from load, but load when the user clickes a button. Anny Idea how to do this? Can I call the CSS from Java like you can from HTML, or is there another way. Thanks for answers

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaScript to programmatically set the CSS that defines the background.

```
var img = "some_image.png";
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
```

Make sure to change the element with the actual HTML element you want to set the background image on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML DOM to do this like the code below

```
<button type="button" 
 onclick="document.getElementById('id').style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png')"">
Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

1. handling the event (in thi example click)
2. Append the new css property to the element target

```js
function appendImg() {
  document.getElementById('result').style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Q13U4dlElI8/VSW78iey57I/AAAAAAAAI7k/HO3zYPaRYso/s1600/img_john_lennon2-500.jpg)';
}
```

```css
#result {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="appendImg()">Imagine</button>
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
```